# TypeError: an integer is required while using replace() in python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to parse a date and put it in the correct format, this is what I tried so far:

```
import csv
import sys
import os
import re
import fnmatch
import csv
from dateutil.parser import parse as parseDate
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

chaine = '16/12/201602:15:00'
date = chaine[:10] + " " + chaine[11:]
print date
newd = parseDate(date, yearfirst=True)
print newd
newd = newd.replace('-','')
newd = newd.replace(':','')
print newd
```

This is what I get as result:

```
16/12/2016 2:15:00
2016-12-16 02:15:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 25, in <module>
    newd = newd.replace('-','')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What do I miss here?

Thank you

Comment: `newd` is not a string. Try using `newd = str(newd).replace('-','')` instead of `newd = newd.replace('-','')`.

Comment: thank you! could you put an answer so that i can accept it :)

Comment: if your date is `'16/12/201602:15:00'`, then your setting for `yearfirst` in `parseDate(date, yearfirst=True)` seems to be wrong too, but without effect on the result, so you can drop that option

Comment: That's right! THank you @MaartenFabré

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix your current logic, you need to cast the `newd` variable to a string after `parseDate`:

```
newd = str(newd).replace('-','')
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3OM7lT)

Alternatively, use the `strptime` / `strftime`:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as parseDate
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from time import strftime

chaine = '16/12/201602:15:00'
dt = datetime.strptime(chaine, '%d/%m/%Y%I:%M:%S')
# 16/12/2016 2:15:00
print(dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
#2016-12-16 02:15:00
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
# 20161216 021500
print(dt.strftime("%Y%m%d %H%M%S"))
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/NOLP3D).

Comment: better would be to use `strftime`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: Yes, I know, just did not have time to prepare a demo. Added now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code newd is a datetime.datetime object, not a string. you can see it with

```
print type(newd)  shows <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

so you cannot use a string replacement.
you can use discrete properties like

```
 newd.year .month .day etc.
```

to create your own string.( more on [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)  )
or play more quickly with the **[strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)** method